Is there a way to fold all sections of code found by a search in Visual Studio Code?
I would like to fold all JS doc comments within my code. I just found that folding all comments can be done with Ctrl+K Ctrl+/. Yet I am still wondering if there is a way to fold all occurrences in the code of a searched phrase like /**.
I have searched for "vscode fold all occurrences of a searched phrase", and found this reference page that mentions:

Fold All Block Comments (Ctrl+K Ctrl+/) folds all regions that start with a block comment token.

This folds all comments, including the JS doc comments. However, this still does not allow the folding of code segments that match a search phrase.

what if you place multiple cursors in the JSDoc regions and execute the command Fold Region, use Alt+Enter in Find box when you search for /**

It's unlikely, but there may be an extension.  Code can only be "folded" ("collapsed") where it's possible to do so, eg on a comment or on a class statement (or other block statement) - you can't just collapse random code based on a search string.
